# error no se encuentra SQLserverCompact.dll al generar base de datos de un modelo

Tags: c#, sql-server

quiero generar una base de datos apartir de un modelo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alli dice que no encuentra la `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.dll`, si la buscas en la carpeta, puedes visualizarla ?

Comment: no evaluaste dejar de usar el `.edmx` y pasar a Code First ?

Comment: es mejor Code First?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no esta en la direccion que indica sabes que falta de instalar?

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria revises

[Working with SQL Server Compact 4.0 using Entity Framework 6 and ADO.NET](https://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/d3fa749b20db46b68adb73acee7f2aaf)

Alli lo que plantea es que agregues la libreria usando nuget

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que esto agregar la dll faltante